# Repository Pattern and Mapping between Business Objects and Data Access Objects

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, design-patterns, business-logic

I use Entity Framework as ORM in my .net MVC project. I've implemented the Repository-Pattern (generic) to get/save/update/remove DAOs (Data Access Objects). I also have Business Objects which contain all the business logic. I have - for example - a DAO called Student and a BO (Business Object) called Student as well. The BO contains the logic, the DAO just the data stored in the DB.
Now I am wondering if the Student-Repository should return the Business-Object instead of the DAO?
I could achieve that using Automapper by converting the DAO to a Business Object before returning it from the Repository.Get(). Same with all the other methods. But is this a good practice?

**Update**

I have a Data Access Layer project and a project for the Business Logic. Entity Framework creates its entities in partial classes (into the Data Access Project) so I could actually extend the entities with other partial classes but the problem is that I reference the Data Access Project in my Business project and I don't have access to the logic code within the Data Access project. So I have to put the logic inside the Business project but as it is not possible to create partial classes over two projects I have to go another way... or do you have a good idea how to structure and solve the problem in a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMHO there are several goals (some competing):

- Make business logic testable in isolation
- Design domain objects to match your domain
- Decouple data access from everything else
- Keep it simple

Can you test your business logic without a database? Probably yes, whether the classes are EF POCO entities or mapped from DAOs.

Do your domain objects match your domain? Are their names well-chosen? Are they always in a valid state? (This can be difficult with a bunch of public read/write properties.) Domain-driven design considerations apply here. (I'm no expert in that.)

Could you swap out EF for Dapper, SQL Server for MongoDB, or current data access for a web service call without changing anything outside the data access layer - with confidence? My suspicion is no. Generic repositories tend to leak IQueryable into other layers. Not everything supports querying, and provider implementations vary. Unit tests typically use LINQ to Objects, which does **not** behave the same as LINQ to Entities. Also, if you want to extract a web service contract, you would have to look through all classes to find all the queries. See [IQueryable is Tight Coupling](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/26/IQueryableTisTightCoupling/).

Finally, do you need all of this? If your application's purpose is CRUD data access with no business logic above simple validation, maybe not. These considerations definitely apply to a complex application or site.

Comment: Thank you TrueWill! I appreciate your help. My application is (or is going to be) quite complex. I think a more separated code would improve the maintainability very much? One other problem I am facing is the one I described in one of the comments above (answer to lazyberezovsky).

Comment: For a complex app, I agree with separating the DAL project from the domain/business logic project. DAOs are also a reasonable choice.

Comment: Excellent advice. I had to deduce the answer I was looking for from the phrase "Generic repositories tend to leak IQueryable into other layers", but that's fine.

Comment: @JonKoeter I'm open to extending this answer; how would you phrase what you were looking for?

Comment: @TrueWill I would say "Where do I map my DTO's / Data objects / Entities to my Domain Objects, should it be in the business layer or in the Repository?". And I guess I was thinking all experienced programmers think it's obvious, so that would be the reason for it not being explicit. But when you said it's bad for IQueryables to leak into other layers, it was clear to me. Map your stuff in the repository, keep the rest of your solution clean, using only domainobjects with only the necessary information, for reasons mentioned earlier (for example: swapping EF for Dapper, etc). Thanks again!

Comment: @JonKoeter There are several good answers to your question at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/306658/in-ddd-should-repositories-expose-an-entity-or-domain-objects (note that a DDD Entity is a type of domain object and has nothing to do with EF).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's totally good practice. Usually you have repository interfaces defined in domain assembly. These interfaces are used by domain services, and implemented in persistence assembly. Entity Framework allows you to map business entities fluently, without polluting them with attributes or forcing them to inherit from some specific base class (POCO entities). That makes your domain model Persistence Ignorant.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I thought about mapping the business objects to the dao's and vice versa with AutoMapper. You are writing about doing that with Entity Framework right? - How can you achieve that?

Comment: @sjkm what benefits DAO brings to your application? If you will rename table or column in database, then you can simply change mapping. Business entity will stay the same. I don't see any benefits. What I see is two new places to create and maintain - DAO and mapping between DAO and BO.

Comment: I have a Data Access Layer project and a project for the Business Logic. Entity Framework creates its entities in partial classes so I could actually extend the entities with other partial classes but the problem is that I reference the DAL-project in my Business project and I don't have access to the logic code within the DAL-project. So I have to put the logic inside the Business project but as it is not possible to create partial classes over two projects I have to go another way... or do you have a good idea how to structure and solve the problem in a better way? I really appreciate it!